# Is it possible to convert postcript font to otf/ttf?

Tags: fonts, .ttf

I have some ps fonts that are not recogniced by libreoffice. I'd like to convert it to a libreoffice compatible format .ttf/otf so that I can use it.  Is it possible to do the conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with converting Type 1 fonts is they have a limited number of characters and don't support unicode. Many Type 1 fonts have already been converted and extended. Here are a few packages:

```
fonts-urw-base35
fonts-texgyre
fonts-lmodern
```

If you would still like to convert the fonts yourself, you can use **FontForge**.

```
sudo apt install fontforge
```

To convert from the command line, you can create the following bash function:

```
function ffconvert {
   fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1); Generate($2)' "$1" "$2"
}
```

Then use it to convert some fonts:

```
ffconvert example.pfb example.otf
```

Or call it from a loop:

```
for f in *.pfb ; do
   ffconvert "$f" "${f%.pfb}.otf"
done
```